# Terraform Azurerm Recovery Services Vault Backup Policy Format Error

Tags: azure, backup, terraform, recovery

I am trying to create a weekly **Azure VM** protection policy in **Terraform** to run on Fridays at 6:30 pm with a retention of 1. TF throws format error related to 'schedule time, schedule days, retention time and retention days' error. I am not exactly sure which parameter has an incorrect value or format.

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "backup_vault" {
  name                = "${var.RG4VM}-recovery-vault"
  location            = "${var.VMLocation}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.RG4VM}"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  depends_on          = ["azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup"]
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm" "backup_policy" {
  name                = "${var.RG4VM}-bkp-policy"
  resource_group_name = "${var.RG4VM}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup_vault.name}"
  depends_on          = ["azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup_vault"]

  backup {
    frequency = "Weekly"
    time      = "18:30"
  }

  retention_weekly {
    count    = 1
    weekdays = ["Friday"]
  }
}
```

Expected:
It should create the policy as per the config defined.

Actual:

> - azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm.backup_policy: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - azurerm_recovery_services_protection_policy_vm.backup_policy: Error creating/updating Recovery Service Protection Policy
>     "Terraform-Linux-Test-RG-bkp-policy" (Resource Group
>     "Terraform-Linux-Test-RG"):
>     backup.ProtectionPoliciesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to
>     request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service
>     returned an error. Status=400 Code="BMSUserErrorInvalidPolicyInput"
>     Message="Input for create or update policy is not in proper
>     format\r\nPlease check format of parameters like schedule time,
>     schedule days, retention time and retention days "

I'd appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Thanks
Asghar

Comment: I rechecked the formatting based on https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/recovery_services_protection_policy_vm.html. Not exactly sure what formatting mistake I am doing. I only want weekly backups to run at 6:30 pm on Fridays with a retention of 1 week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, maybe it's a little mistake that you did. You just need to make a change in the backup block of the policy like this:

```
backup {
    frequency = "Weekly"
    time      = "18:30"
    weekdays  = ["Friday"]
  }
```

Then it will work fine. The screenshot of the test on my side below:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Charles.